# Graphics card pci-e slots for R9-280X

Tags: graphics-card, pci-express

When removing my graphics card I accidentally snapped the clip off the pci-e slot. 
I've got an R9-280X graphics card on an ASUS® Z87M-PLUS: m-ATX motherboard.

I've put the graphics card back in and it works fine. I haven't noticed any difference in performance. Is there anything I should be worried about?

On the user manual for the motherboard it says

---

- 1x PCI Express 3.0/2.0 x16 slot (at x16 mode)
- 1x PCI Express 2.0 x16 slot (run at x4 mode, compaticle with PCIe x1 anc x4 devices)
- 2x PCI Express 2.0 x1 slots

(* The PCIe x16_2 slot shares bandwidth with PCIe x1_2 slot. The default setting is x2 mode. Go to BIOS setup to change the settings.)

---

Would I be able to use a different PCI slot instead. Is there any BIOS change necessary (re what is on the user manual) if I decide to use a different slot.

Thanks

Comment: Not having a clip on the PIC-E slot is not a big deal as long as the card is securely fastened to the case. I actually took off the clips on my motherboard because it was extremely difficult to un-clip them and remove the graphics card.

Comment: @AnDorfer Thanks very much, fell a lot better now ;)

Answer (score 3):

The clip at the end of the PCI-E slot just helps hold the graphics card in place. There is nothing to worry about as long as the case is stable. You can use any other slot that is on the motherboard without changing any BOIS settings.